# Winforms Databinding Notification

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

My model is mainly made from the 2 classes below (I actually got another class which inherits from the abstract class but it doesnt matter I think):

```
public abstract class FeedForEvents: BaseObservableObject
{
    public abstract void ReadFeed();
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public void AddEvent(Event aEvent)
    {
        Events.Add(aEvent);
        OnPropertyChanged("Events");
    }
}

public class Event : BaseObservableObject
{
    public string MyProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProp;
        }
        set
        {
            _myprop= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

My form contains:

```
private BindingList<FeedForEvents> ListFeedsForEvents = new BindingList<FeedForEvents>();
private BindingList<Event> ListEvents 
            => new BindingList<Event>(ListFeedsForEvents.SelectMany(m =>m.Events).ToList());
   private BindingSource pagesBindingSource = new BindingSource();
   public void RefreshGrid()
   {
            pagesBindingSource.DataSource = ListEvents;
            this.grdEvents.DataSource = pagesBindingSource;
            this.grdEvents.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
   }
```

But even if my 2 objects correctly raised the PropertyChanged notficiation, the interface never show the objects updated (unless I manually refresh them by pressing a button to manually call `RefreshGrid()` ). Why?

Comment: List doesn't report changes to the list — use a BindingList for that.  Your Event class needs to raise the PropertyChanged event for the properties that are changing.  You left that code out of your post.

Comment: Thanks. So BindingList<BindingList<Event>> ?

Comment: That's a list of a list.  I'm guessing you just want `BindingList<Event>`.

Comment: Please find my updated code with more details. thanks